# Identificar o valor de uma celula da linha clicada de uma tabela html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou tentando identificar qual o email do `tr` que foi clicado. O meu problema é que independente do `tr` que eu clique, sempre me retorna o mesmo valor.

Obs: Gostaria de saber o valor da celula, não da linha inteira.

```js
$("#modelTable > tbody").delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
   console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].textContent);
});
```

```css
#modelTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
#modelTable td, #modelTable th{
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}
#modelTable th{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
}
#modelTable td{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#modelTable tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#modelTable tr:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#modelTable th{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modelTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">Id User</spam></th>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">UserEmail</spam></th>
  </tr>                          
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>email1@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>email2@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como posso solucionar este problema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só trocar `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1]` por `this`. Mas como o colega @LeAndrade comento não use `.delegate`, pense e usar dessa forma por exemplo para evitar problemas no futuro!

```
`$("#modelTable tbody tr").on('click', function() { }`
```

Para pegar apenas o último td vc pode usar `$(this).children().last()`

Segue o seu código com o ajuste completo. Deixei o `.delegate`, mas sugiro que use como acima.

```js
    $("#modelTable tbody tr").on('click', function() {
      let td = $(this).children().last();
        console.log(td.text());
    });
```

```css
#modelTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
}

#modelTable td,
#modelTable th {
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

#modelTable th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#modelTable td {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#modelTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#modelTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#modelTable th {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="modelTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <spam class="lang" key="">Id User</spam>
            </th>
            <th>
                <spam class="lang" key="">UserEmail</spam>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>email1@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>email2@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Respondemos juntos hehe só que a sua foi melhor que a minha, pois utilizei o each sem necessidade ;) . Só alerta ele pra trocar o delegate por on.

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado pela resposta. realmente funcionou, contudo gostaria de pegar somente o email, e não linha toda. Não estou conseguindo abstrair a tag 'td' do 'this'.

Comment: @LeAndrade obrigado pela observação! Deixei a menção na edição ;)

Comment: @Levi agora ficou mas claro o que precisa, pois na sua pergunta vc não fala nada de pegar apenas o email... na verdade é quase que outra pergunta o que vc está falando agora. Pois na pegunta vc fala de TR não de conteúdo da apenas uma TD etc...

Comment: @hugocsl Perdão por não ter me feito compreendido. Irei editar a pergunta.

Comment: @Levi atualizei o script, agora pega só o texto da última td

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado, marquei sua resposta pois achei sua resolução melhor.

Comment: Opa :D, as explicações do @Sam são bem pertinentes, mas valeu a força  se facilita pra vc é isso que importa. Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de pegar somente o **email**:

```js
$("#modelTable > tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
      console.log($(this).text().split('\n')[2].trim());
});
```

```css
#modelTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
#modelTable td, #modelTable th{
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}
#modelTable th{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
}
#modelTable td{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#modelTable tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#modelTable tr:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#modelTable th{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modelTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">Id User</spam></th>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">UserEmail</spam></th>
  </tr>                          
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>email1@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>email2@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Jovem para que serve esse `'\n'`?

Comment: É que os textos estão em uma tabela, estou pegando os textos com o método text() do jQuery, e ele entende os textos em cada coluna como uma quebra de linha **\n**,  aí então quando dou o `split('\n')` assim separo os textos por linha. Não sei se deu pra entender direito ;)

Comment: Acho que entendi, seria para colocar ou deixar quebrar o texto da célula em linhas. Valeu o toque, vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto, já vi uns \r, \n por ai e nunca entendi direito para que servem

Answer (score 1):

O `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1]` sempre irá retornar o mesmo elemento porque você está pegando o **segundo** elemento na página que contém a tag `tr`.

O `document.getElementsByTagName` retorna um *node list* (lista de nós) que é indexado com base `0`, onde `[0]` é o primeiro elemento, `[1]` o segundo e por aí vai.

Além do que se você está usando jQuery, não precisa usar `document.getElementsByTagName`. Pode pegar o elemento que disparou o evento com `$(this)`, e para pegar o texto dentro do elemento, você usa `$(this).text()`.

E você inverteu a ordem dos argumentos. O evento vem antes do elemento: seria `'click', 'tr'` e não `'tr', 'click'`. E não use `.delegate` porque é um método descontinuado do jQuery, e embora funcione, será removido a qualquer nova versão.

E também não precisa usar `>`, pois o `tbody` já é descendente da tabela. E é preciso pegar o texto apenas da coluna onde está o email, que é a segunda coluna. Neste caso você pode usar o seletor jQuery `:eq()`, que também é de base `0`. Ou seja, para pegar a segunda coluna você usa `:eq(1)`. E use também o `.trim()`, pois ao pegar o texto de um elemento HTML, é possível às vezes vir com espaços nas bordas.

O código ficaria assim:

```js
$("#modelTable tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
   var email = $('td:eq(1)', this).text().trim();
   console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modelTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">Id User</spam></th>
    <th><spam class="lang" key="">UserEmail</spam></th>
  </tr>                          
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>email1@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>email2@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```